# How to keep a cell number in a formula when adding rows on top

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have the following formula in cell `M8`:

```
{=SUM((MOD(ROW(M$16:$M977)-ROW($M$16),4)=0)*(M$16:$M977))}
```

with this formula a get the total hours per week on column M from every fourth row staring on M16, such m16+m20+m24+m28, etc. I keep adding the new data  on top so when I open up the spreadsheet I will have the most current info on top. When add the four new rows for my new data the formula looks like:

```
{=SUM((MOD(ROW(M$20:$M977)-ROW($M$20),4)=0)*(M$20:$M977))}
```

How do I get it to always start adding on M16, because that is where my new total hours for the new week will be.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/691164/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-write-an-array-formula-to-facilitate-the-addition-of?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Put the value of M16 at the bottom of the file or in a cell that you don't move! 
In fact, every time you add a row, automatically every reference to cell is modified!

Answer (score 0):

First, you should change this to a `SUMPRODUCT` formula. It doesn't require that you enter it as an array formula and - IMHO - it's easier to use.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(M16:M977*(MOD(ROW(M16:M977)-ROW(M16),4)=0))
```

---

To get around Excel's behavior when you insert rows, I recommend turning your data into a table. (Insert ribbon > Table) It makes referencing "all the data in this area" really easy and it updates the way you want whenever the table gets larger or smaller. In that case, the formula would look something like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Table1[Hours]*(MOD(ROW(Table1[Hours])-ROW(Table1[[#Headers],[Hours]])-1,4)=0))
```

---

If you can't turn it into a table for some reason, I'd recommend creating a named range and referencing that instead. The formula for the named range would be:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet3!$M$1,15,0,MATCH(9E+99,Sheet3!$M:$M)-15)
```

... and the formula referencing it would be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(rngHours*(MOD(ROW(rngHours)-ROW(OFFSET(rngHours,0,0,1,1)),4)=0))
```

... where `rngHours` is whatever name you gave the named range.

---

If you really don't want to used named ranges, you can squish the whole thing into one big formula but it's going to get messy, albeit function:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET(Sheet3!$M$1,15,0,MATCH(9E+99,Sheet3!$M:$M)-15)*(MOD(ROW(OFFSET(Sheet3!$M$1,15,0,MATCH(9E+99,Sheet3!$M:$M)-15))-ROW(OFFSET(Sheet3!$M$1,15,0)),4)=0))
```